# Codeigniter friendly url

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I try to pass the parameters from controller to url.
I try to achieve something like this: `http://localhost/management_system/Job/search_job?keyword=word&location=location`

for now i only get `http://localhost/management_system/Job/search_job`
Dose somebody know how i can achieve that?
Below you can see my controller:

```
    public function search_job(){

    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $location = $this->input->post('location', TRUE);
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword', TRUE);

        $data['all_jobs'] = $this->Job_model->search_job($keyword, $location);

            if ($data['all_jobs'] > 0 ) {
                $data['categoryes'] = $this->Job_model->get_category();
                $this->autoload('job_list', 'eJobs', $data);
            }
        }else{
            redirect('Job/jobs');
        }
}
```

Comment: how you are generating the url. For your information, the url you mentioned can be achieved through get method. as i see your controller, you have validation for post method. I am not getting the clear picture, can you explain further.

Answer (score 0):

In your action you are waiting for a POST request but this: http://localhost/management_system/Job/search_job?keyword=word&location=location is a GET request.

If your request is this: http://localhost/management_system/Job/search_job?keyword=word&location=location 
and you want to get `location` and `keyword` you must write code like this:

```
public function search_job() {

    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $location = $this->input->get('location', TRUE);
        $keyword = $this->input->get('keyword', TRUE);

        $data['all_jobs'] = $this->Job_model->search_job($keyword, $location);

        if ($data['all_jobs'] > 0 ) {
            $data['categoryes'] = $this->Job_model->get_category();
            $this->autoload('job_list', 'eJobs', $data);
        }
    } else {
        redirect('Job/jobs');
    }
}
```

You need to change

```
$this->input->post()
```

to

```
$this->input->get()
```

Comment: I've done that but when i search now the function dosen't work

Comment: it comes from your route config you must set a rout in your routes.php config 
if you controller name is Job and you action name is search_job you will add in your route config  it will be like this 
$route['Job/search_job/(:any)'] = 'Job/search_job/$1';

Comment: I dont have example, I know Codeigniter very well, for your example I thing it not works becouse of if ($this->input->post('submit')) { do you sure that you sends post request with submit key?